# установка sqldeveloper на ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, java, sqldeveloper

При первой попытке запуска sqldeveloper система запрашивает полный путь установленного JDK. 
Для того, чтобы узнать полную путь до jdk я использую команду `update-alternatives --config java`. Она мне выводит следующее сообщение `Есть только одна альтернатива в группе ссылок java (предоставляющая /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
Настраивать нечего.`

Я так понимаю, что этот путь и есть полный путь до jdk? Вставляю данный адрес при запуске sqldeveloper, возникает ошибка `Error: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java/bin/java not found or not a valid JDK`

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2):

Полный путь нужно было указать `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`, а не `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java`.

Comment: Вообще, до `/bin` надо.